# Sort int range as PostgreSQL date range

Tags: postgresql, sorting, date, integer, range

Because BC dates in PostgreSQL only stop at 4713 BC and I don't want to limit the BC dates in general, I decided to use int as dates.

Here is my table after doing `select * from test order by daterange;`:

```
id  daterange
26  [-6000501,-6000301)
27  [-6000401,-6000201)
22  [-4001202,-4000102)
23  [-4000702,-4000302)
19  [-3010102,-3000102)
21  [-3001202,-3000102)
14  [-3001011,-2000101)
15  [-1000506,6000701)
20  [3000102,3001201)
16  [12500709,13650230)
17  [14580102,16590507)
```

There are int ranges that represent chronological eras. Negative numbers are the BC dates. The pattern is `YYYYMMDD`.

Problem is that `id 27 [-6000401,-6000201)` should be first and `id 26 [-6000501,-6000301)` second because BC dates are flipped: upper bounds are chronologically first. Also, months inside a year don't descent, they ascent. But PostgreSQL tries to save negative numbers, not having a clue about chronological content. So they should be ordered like so:

1. -6000201, then -6000401 (600BC February, then April)
2. -6000301, then -6000501 (600BC March, then May)

Therefore:

```
id 27 [-6000401,-6000201)  -- first
id 26 [-6000501,-6000301)  -- second
```

To be clear, I don't want to switch the bounds inside the ranges -that's impossible. I want to flip the sorting order according to the max bound, just like above. I don't know how to sort this kind of ranges. It should sort them according to their upper limit, `DESC` I guess? I tried something like

```
SELECT * FROM test  
ORDER BY daterange ASC 
, CASE WHEN (upper(daterange)<0) AND (lower(daterange)<0) THEN daterange END DESC;
```

But I get the same order. I use PostgreSQL 10.

Maybe there is some other workaround or method that I didn't think at all. Or maybe a plugin for unlimited BC dates - even though I didn't find any.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter Thanks for the tips, edited my question

Comment: So do you have your answer?

Answer (score 1):

While stuck with your creative date format, this should achieve the proper ascending sort order:

```
SELECT *
     , upper(daterange), upper(daterange)/10000, upper(daterange)%10000
     , lower(daterange), lower(daterange)/10000, lower(daterange)%10000
FROM   test  
ORDER  BY CASE WHEN upper(daterange) >= 0 THEN daterange END NULLS FIRST 
                                       -- BC before AD, fully sort AD
        , upper(daterange)/10000       -- BC by start year
        , upper(daterange)%10000 DESC  -- BC by start date
        , lower(daterange)/10000       -- BC by end year
        , lower(daterange)%10000 DESC; -- BC by end date
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=21ee7e57289973545498c208e5b4183d)*

The `CASE` expression defaults to `NULL` for BC dates and those are sorted first (without differentiating further, yet). About `NULLS FIRST`:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)

The next 4 expressions sort BC dates according to your rules. You might add `CASE WHEN upper(daterange) < 0` to each, but since AD dates are fully sorted already, it wouldn't make a difference. Maybe for performance, but not much.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL `date` type is indeed limited to 4713 BC. But it can reach 5874897 AD - almost 6 million years!

I hope that you don't need to store dates in all 6 million years range. What you can do is to add a million (or two) years to your dates and you will fit in the range that PostgreSQL supports. Just think that you have *shifted* the dates.

For example, instead of `600-02-01 BC` you can store `999400-02-01 AD` (+1'000'000 years).

And you can switch from `int4range` to `daterange`. You will get proper sorting for free.

All you need to remember is to subtract the years that you have added before displaying the date.